# CMD/Python: Guess your .docx or .txt file's encoding

Tags: python, cmd.exe, encoding, python3

Ok, I want to find out, what kind of files I have, for encoding. I tried to read the file with encoding='UTF-8' and it failed, which indicates that the document is not utf8-encoded. Of course, I could try another encoding, such as 'ascii' or 'latin-1' or 'cp1252'. I could also install the chardet module and use it to detect your file's encoding.

I could try the following in a terminal / **cmd tool** to guess your file's encoding

**Output:**

```
python -m chardet.cli.chardetect FILENAME
```

For Python. For example I have a file named 'ham' and here is the output with this command

**Output:**

```
λ python -m chardet.cli.chardetect ham
ham: ascii with confidence 1.0
```

**Does anyone have a better solution to find out what encoding have my .docx files?**

Does anyone know how to use **chardet module** to detect my file's encoding? The code exactly, because I cannot find any good and complete code for this library.

Comment: For docx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172022/character-encoding-of-microsoft-word-doc-and-docx-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docx file produced by Word is a ZIP file containing UTF-8 XML files.

The encoding of each XML file is in the XML header. Typically `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"…`.

Then you can’t open a docx file directly as a UTF-8 text file.